# UnsupportedClassVersionError even though Java versions match

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error, version, unsupported-class-version

I'm getting an error when I try to run my program. Here's the error:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: me/icc/pluginTest/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

But in my terminal window, when I type java -version:

```
java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And I thought Java 13 was v57. From what I see my JRE matches my Java version. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Extra photos if that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u23pz.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: Somehow it's trying to launch using a different installation. Provide more details about how you "run your program".

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5ZPZMFcB it says I'm using 1.8.0, but I don't have that checked
https://imgur.com/a/28d7XZv

I've tried different Java versions and different JREs and I get the same error every time, regardless of the version.